# how to pass excel file to C# controller from angular 4 in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: excel, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2017, epplus

In my web application, I have to import an excel file and want to pass the same to Server side controller.

In Server side I have used EPPlus.

How can I achieve the same?

Anyone please help to achieve the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file input in your template

```
<input type="file" #fileInput />
<button (click)="uploadFile();">Upload</button>
```

Then head over to your component

```
@ViewChild('fileInput') fileInput;
// inject httpclient from @angular/common/http
...
public uploadFile(): void {
   if (this.fileInput.files.length === 0) {
      return; // maybe needs more checking
   }

   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', this.fileInput.files[0]);
   this.http.post('http://my-url/api/my-endpoint', formData).subscibre(...); // the usual
}
```

Now in your API create an endpoint like that

```
[HttpPost]
// the name here must be file for the parameter, bc you declared it as such in your formdata
public IActionResult UploadFile([FromBody] IFormFile file)
{
    // depending on what you wanna do you can either create and store it in the filesystem or copy the file into a byte array and store it in your db
}
```

If you clarify where you want to save the file I can expand the C# code. But in general this is how you receive the file from the front-end, in your back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of similar questions for uploading files, or 3rd party pre-made components to use...

- [File Upload In Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214772/file-upload-in-angular)
- [PrimeNg File upload](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload)

And plenty of similar questions and examples regarding receiving files server-side...

- [asp.net - How to upload file with web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13736548/how-to-upload-file-with-web-api)
- [Upload Files In ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-files-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)
- [Etc.](https://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/)